# Trying to build a calorie calculator and getting an "invalid syntax" error

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator that asks how many calories eaten for the day then adds the amount for each day and prints the total intake for the week but I am getting an invalid syntax error. Here is the code i've written so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
print("Monday")

m = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Tuesday")

tues = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Wednesday")

w = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Thursday")

thurs = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Friday")

f = (input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Saturday")

s = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Sunday")

sun = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

sum = m + tues + w + thurs + f + s + sun

print("Amount of calories this week!", sum)
```

Comment: Is there meant to be an extra open parentheses here:  f = (input('How many calories did you consume today?')

Comment: regardless of the syntax error, input function returns a string and not an integer, you need to use ```int(input("what's your age"))```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems
First, there's an extra bracket here

```py
f = (input('How many calories did you consume today?')
```

Get rid of it, it's probably causing your error. It should look like

```py
f = input('How many calories did you consume today?')
```

Another problem is that you won't actually get numerical adding. You will get string concatenation. To fix this, you need to use the `int` or `float` class.
Your code needs to look like this

```py
print("Monday")

m = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Tuesday")

tues = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Wednesday")

w = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Thursday")

thurs = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Friday")

f = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Saturday")

s = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Sunday")

sun = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

sum = m + tues + w + thurs + f + s + sun

print("Amount of calories this week!", sum)
```

or

```py
print("Monday")

m = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Tuesday")

tues = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Wednesday")

w = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Thursday")

thurs = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Friday")

f = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Saturday")

s = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

print("Sunday")

sun = input('How many calories did you consume today?')

sum = int(m) + int(tues) + int(w) + int(thurs) + int(f) + int(s) + int(sun)

print("Amount of calories this week!", sum)
```

Why is this?
If the inputs aren't converted, they and the user enters `1`, `4`, `2`, and `5` for example sake.
Without the conversion, your sum would look like `1425` as it's combining two strings together.
When converted to an `int`, you get `12` as your output.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a `)` before the `print("Saturday")` syntax

Secondly, if you want to add the numbers, you have to convert them to either `int` or `float`

```
print("Monday")

m = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Tuesday")

tues = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Wednesday")

w = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Thursday")

thurs = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Friday")

f = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Saturday")

s = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

print("Sunday")

sun = int(input('How many calories did you consume today?'))

sum = m + tues + w + thurs + f + s + sun

print("Amount of calories this week!", sum)
```